# How to escape Jenkins parameterized build variables

Tags: jenkins, escaping

I use `Jenkins ver. 1.522` and I want to pass a long string with spaces and quotes as a parameter in the parameterized build section. The job only runs a python script.

My problem is that I can't find a way to escape my string so that jenkins passes it correctly to the script.

Assuming...

string: `fixVersion in ("foo") AND issuetype in (Bug, Improvement) AND resolution = Fixed ORDER BY resolution ASC, assignee ASC, key DESC`

variable name: bar

script name: coco.py

When I run the script in the terminal, everything is fine: `python coco.py --option 'fixVersion in ("foo") AND issuetype in (Bug, Improvement) AND resolution = Fixed ORDER BY resolution ASC, assignee ASC, key DESC'`

When I run the same script with jenkins using the parametrized build and try to escape the variable so it end up taken as one parameter by the py script it is oddly espacped by jenkins.

In my jenkins job I call the script: `python coco.py --option \'${BAR}\'`

and it ends up as:

`python coco.py --option '"fixVersion' in '('\''foo'\'')' AND issuetype in '(Bug,' 'Improvement)' in '(Production,' 'Stage)' AND resolution = Fixed ORDER BY resolution ASC, assignee ASC, key 'DESC"'`

I also tried `\"${BAR}\"`, `\"$BAR\"`,`\'$BAR\'`

What it the right way do acheive it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
python coco.py --option "${BAR}"
```

Alternatively, if you need the single quotes surrounding everything

```
python coco.py --option \'"${BAR}"\'
```

In the cases you listed, bash will treat the spaces as delimiters. Putting the double quotes around a variable will preserve the whitespace in a string. Example

```
aString='foo bar'
for x in $aString; do echo $x; done
# foo
# bar
for x in "$aString"; do echo $x; done
# foo bar
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using Jenkins v1.606 and ran into this same issue!
The issue that I saw passing user defined string params containing spaces into an execution shell would not properly format the string (only with a parameter that had 1 or more spaces). What you have to watch out for is reviewing the 'output' log. Jenkins will not properly display the string param value within the log.

**Example** (*correct format for containing spaces*):

```
docker exec -i container-base /bin/bash -c "cd /container/path/to/code/ && ./gradlew test_xml -P DISPLAY_NAME='${DISPLAY_NAME}' -P USERNAME='${USERNAME}' -P SERVER_NAME='${SERVER_NAME}'"
```

**Jenkins Output** of string (notice the string values format):

```
+ docker exec -i container-base /bin/bash -c 'cd /container/path/to/code/ && ./gradlew test_xml -P DISPLAY_NAME='\''VM10 USER D33PZ3R0'\'' -P USERNAME='\''d33pz3r0@stackoverflow.com'\'' -P SERVER_NAME='\''stackoverflow.com'\'''
```

**Conclusion:**
In my example, the literal command was encapsulated with <">, followed by surrounding the parameters with <'> to escape the literal cmd string and control the Jenkins string syntax. Remember not to just watch your Jenkins output log as it lead me wrong for an entire day while I fought with this! This should be the same for your issue as well, you do not need to escape with \' or other escape characters. Hope this helps!!